# LibGit2Sharp get repository changes after pull

Tags: c#, git, git-commit, pull, libgit2sharp

How can i get the following information after a git-pull with libgit2sharp:

1. Which files has been moved
2. Which files has been created
3. Which files has been deleted

The git-pull request it self works perfectly:

```
var result = repo.Network.Pull(new LibGit2Sharp.Signature("admin", "mail@......net", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now)), options);
```

I already looked at the result of the `Pull`-Method, but this seems not to contain the needed information.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MergeResult` type exposes a `Commit` property which is not null when the merge was successful.

In order to find out what files have changed, one just have to leverage the `repo.Diff.Compare()` method to compare this `Commit` with its first parent.