# LibGit2Sharp Find what files were updated/added/deleted after pull

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

After running a `repo.Network.Pull()` command I want to be able to see what files were added to the repository, altered in the repository and removed from the repository. All I need is the file path of the file and if it was an add/update or a delete.

Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried looking into `Diff.Compare()` but I'm not sure if that is the right way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LibGit2Sharp get repository changes after pull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758362/libgit2sharp-get-repository-changes-after-pull)

Comment: `Diff.Compare` is indeed the way to go ;-) Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758362/libgit2sharp-get-repository-changes-after-pull/30759152#30759152 for further detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibGit2Sharp 0.21.0.176

Here is an libGit2 example of walking your current commit tree and getting the files that changed and the type of change.

Git version:

```
git log --name-status --pretty=oneline

1d9d4bb881f97f5d3b67741a893f238e7221e2b1 Updated readme with fork info
M       README.md
58cc5c41963d5ff68556476158c9c0c2499e061c Update Makefile for PE32+ (platform:x64) assemblies
M       Makefile
M       README.md
a7823c1c0a737c5218d33691f98828c78d52130b Fix Makefile for 64-bit native lib and add README.md
M       Makefile
A       README.md
ea7e6722f67569cb9d7a433ff2c036fc630d8561 Update solution files.
M       mono-curses.csproj
M       mono-curses.sln
05dbe6e18895d1037ce333b0a1f652eeae3f8b33 Fix resize handling.
M       attrib.c
M       gui.cs
```

libGit2 version:

```
    var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository ("/your/repo/path");
    foreach (Commit commit in repo.Commits) {
        foreach (var parent in commit.Parents) {
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} | {1}", commit.Sha, commit.MessageShort);
            foreach (TreeEntryChanges change in repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parent.Tree,
            commit.Tree)) {
                Console.WriteLine ("{0} : {1}", change.Status, change.Path);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
1d9d4bb881f97f5d3b67741a893f238e7221e2b1 | Updated readme with fork info
Modified : README.md
58cc5c41963d5ff68556476158c9c0c2499e061c | Update Makefile for PE32+ (platform:x64) assemblies
Modified : Makefile
Modified : README.md
a7823c1c0a737c5218d33691f98828c78d52130b | Fix Makefile for 64-bit native lib and add README.md
Modified : Makefile
Added : README.md
ea7e6722f67569cb9d7a433ff2c036fc630d8561 | Update solution files.
Modified : mono-curses.csproj
Modified : mono-curses.sln
05dbe6e18895d1037ce333b0a1f652eeae3f8b33 | Fix resize handling.
Modified : attrib.c
Modified : gui.cs
```

In directly answering to your question, just grab the first commit from the Commits enumerator and compare its tree to its parents (could be more than one parent due to a merge) vs. my example of looping all the commits in the current branch.

Comment: If i pull and then grab the first commits how would i know how many parents it has (due to merges). Would commit.Parents handle that?

Comment: A commit will have 1 or more parents if a merge occurred. i.e. This array (commit.Parents.Select (p => p.Id.Sha).ToArray ()) will contain each parent's commit's SHA.